# Show custom dialog message on deleting row in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jqgrid

I want to show custom dialog message while deleting row from jqgrid.
I am throwing error code from server for each condition which I want to check before delete record from database.

PHP Code :-

```
if($request_array['id']==$_SESSION['login_user_id']){
        http_response_code(423);
        exit;
    }
    else if(!sync_user($request_array['id'])){
        http_response_code(410);
        exit;   
    }
    exit;
```

Javascript code (jqGrid) :

```
      {
       //Delete
       errorTextFormat: function (response) {
        if(response.status==423){
          return [false, "<?php echo "USER_GRID_DELETE_MESSAGE"; ?>"];
        }
        else if(response.status==410){
            return[false,"<?php echo "USER_SYNC_MESSAGE"; ?>"];
        }
       },
      afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
      console.log(response);
       if(response.status==200){
          jQuery.jgrid.info_dialog("<?php echo "GRID_SUCESS_MESSAGE"; ?>","<div class=\"ui-state-highlight\" style=\"padding:5px;\"><?php echo "GRID_RECORD_DELETE_MESSAGE"; ?></div>", 
          jQuery.jgrid.edit.bClose,{buttonalign:"right"});
        return [true,""];
        }
      }

      }
```

Currently I am getting message like `error response "Locked" response code 423`

Thanks in advance.